# How to add user in group using LDAP php?

Tags: php, ldap

I tried much time to create a user in the group but could not have been. While I am able to create a user but not in a group. My Group name is RDP and Netmetric is the folder where I am creating a user.

```
if($ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $username, $password) == true)
{ // if ldap bind

$adduserAD["cn"] = $name;// Common name
$adduserAD["givenname"] = $name;
$adduserAD["sn"] = 'Kumar'; // Surname
$adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = $name; // SamaAccountname declare here
$adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = $name;
$adduserAD["objectClass"] = "User"; // Object class user
$adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
$adduserAD['mail'] = $email;
$adduserAD["userPassword"] = $pwd; // set password here
$adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "66080"; 
$base_dn = "cn=".$name.",ou=Netmetric,DC=ntop,DC=local";// base dn
// Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true){
echo "User is created";
}
ldap_close($ldap_conn);                
}else{ 
echo "Not connected with server";               
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a openldap tag on question, I'm assuming you are trying to add users in OpenLDAP database. 
If that is the case you should get an error because **sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName,userAccountControl** attributes are not present in OpenLDAP schema.